# Initializate a variable in a backing bean (to be used in view scope)

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i have a backing bean managed by spring, and it's scope is view
and i have a users page that display all users
and i want to pass to the datatable the list of users variable, and i want to initialize this variable on construction of the page (and use this variable as long as i am still in the page), and i am confused about the best way to initialize the list of users, i have 3 ways on my mind:

Initialize through **constructor**:

```
@Component("user")
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

private List<User> usersList;


public MyBean() {

   usersList=userService.getUsers();

}

}
```

Initialize through **preRender event**:

```
@Component("user")
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

private List<User> usersList;


public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent event){
  if(usersList!=null)
   usersList=userService.getUsers();
}

}
```

Initialize through **@PostConstruct**

```
@Component("user")
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

private List<User> usersList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

   usersList=userService.getUsers();

}


}
```

please advise what is the best way for initialization in the case of view scope, i want to initialize the variable once, and use the exact same variable in the datatable as long as i am still in same page.

Comment: Actually you have only two options - initialization in constructor wont work as `userService` will be injected after bean object is created. I usually do it in @PostConstruct method, but I'm not using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing in constructor is only possible if the `userService` is not an injected dependency. I.e. when you create it manually instead of using `@EJB`, `@Inject` or `@ManagedProperty` or whatever Spring specific.

If the `userService` is indeed an injected dependency, then the `@PostConstruct` is the only right way, because the dependency is injected *after* construction and thus it would be `null` in the constructor.

The `preRender` method is called before **every** render response. It's not called only once.